# how to get ui automator viewer recognized attributes using appium?

Tags: appium

after setting up appium test environment,I can get the screenshot using ui automator viewer tool,the app to test has a checkbox on it. what i want is to get the "checked" property of the checkbox in my code,i have tried " ele.GetAttribute("checked")",but it didn't work,will you show me how to do this?and what attribute name is supported by appium's webelement?

Answer (score 0):

This syntax works for me.

```
driver.findelement(By.className("<className>")).getAttribute("name")
```